# Orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement $w^{\perp\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

For any subspace W of a vector space V, prove that 
$$
W + V^\perp = W^{\perp\perp}.
$$
I am having difficulty showing: 
$$
 W^{\perp\perp} \subseteq W + V^\perp .
$$

Ideas?

Comment: $W^{\perp\perp} =\;$[closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology))$(W\hspace{.03 in}) \;\;$ and $\:\:\: W+V^{\perp} \; = \; W \;\;\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Hi.  It should be "complement"

Comment: But, if $V$ if your vector space (equipped with a bilinear form), then $V^⊥=\{0\}$. Am I wrong?...

Comment: But what if the bilinear form is degenerate?

Comment: Oh... You didn't said that! XD.

Comment: In general $(W^{\perp})^{\perp}\neq W$.